# Is OAuth2Client (NXOAuth2Client) supports OAuth2 Implicit Grant?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

Implemented iOS app using Oauth2Client but there is new requirement: Implicit Grant. 
Is OAuth2Client (NXOAuth2Client) supports OAuth2 Implicit Grant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client/issues/145

toto commented on Oct 31, 2014

Nope, we support all but implicit flow. We support:

Resource Owner Password Credentials

Authorization Code (the default)

Assertion Flow